# can we disable Kibana Version Mismatch alert

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

we have two kibana instance in a cluster with two different versions and getting alerts from the cluster "Kibana Version Mismatch". using Xpack monitoring. 
Is there any way to disable this cluster alert.

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you upgrade Kibana to the right version?

Comment: thank you! but we cannot change one of the kibana as its a costume kibana instance. is there any other way to stop the alerts instead of keeping the both kibana versions same?